# Proof of Blumenthal's $0-1$ Law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation, brownian-motion

**Statement:** The $σ$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{0+}$ is trivial in the sense that $\mathbb{P}[A] = 0$ or $1$ for every $A ∈ \mathcal{F}_{0+}$, where $\mathcal{F}_{0+}=\bigcap_{s>0}\mathcal{F}_s$

The proof I'm looking at starts like this:

**Proof:** Let $0 < t_1 < t_2 ··· < t_k$ and let $g : \mathbb{R}^k
 → \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function.
Also, fix $A ∈ \mathcal{F}_{0+}$. Then by a continuity argument,
$$\mathbb{E}[1_Ag(B_{t_1}
,...,B_{t_k}
)] = \lim_{
ε↓0}
\mathbb{E}[1_Ag(B_{t_1} −B_ε ,...,B_{t_k} −B_ε )]$$

What I don't understand is the continuity argument - we are really interchanging an integral with a limit without explicit enough conditions to use MCT, DCT etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g$ is bounded, the Bounded Convergence Theorem allows the swapping of $\Bbb E$ and $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}$.
$$\lim_{
ε↓0}
\mathbb{E}[1_Ag(B_{t_1} −B_ε ,...,B_{t_k} −B_ε )] = \Bbb{E}[\lim\limits_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} 1_A g(B_{t_1} - B_\epsilon, \dots, B_{t_k} - B_\epsilon)]$$
Pass the limit sign into the bracket as $g$ is continuous.
$$\Bbb{E}[\lim\limits_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} 1_A g(B_{t_1} - B_\epsilon, \dots, B_{t_k} - B_\epsilon)] = \Bbb{E}[1_A g(\lim\limits_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} (B_{t_1} - B_\epsilon, \dots, B_{t_k} - B_\epsilon))]$$
Since the brownian motion $B_t$ has continous trajectory, $B_\epsilon \to B_0 = 0$ as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$.
$$\Bbb{E}[1_A g(\lim\limits_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} (B_{t_1} - B_\epsilon, \dots, B_{t_k} - B_\epsilon))] = \mathbb{E}[1_Ag(B_{t_1},\dots,B_{t_k})]$$
Combine the equalities to end the proof.